# Find mean from a categorical variable of range (e.g. mean of 30-35) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to calculate the mean of a category variable of range. Here is the example:

```
dt = {"var1": ["1-2", "3-4","6-8","Missing"], 
      "Wanted result": ["1.5", "3.5","7","Missing"]}
pd.DataFrame(dt)
    var1      Wanted result
0   1-2       1.5
1   3-4       3.5
2   6-8       7
3   Missing   Missing
```

How can I get the "Wanted result" from "var1"?

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the with `to_numeric`

```
s=df.var1.str.split('-',expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').mean(axis=1).fillna(df.var1)
0        1.5
1        3.5
2          7
3    Missing
dtype: object
df['wanted']=s
```